# Import test failed when using Conda Build

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I am trying to create my own Conda package, but I'm having a problem when I go to "Build" the package, specifically within the "Testing" phase.  I have been following the tutorial linked below, and it's been very helpful in explaining what each part is doing.

http://kylepurdon.com/blog/packaging-python-basics-with-continuum-analytics-conda.html

Everything seems to build fine until it gets to the testing phase when it fails.

```
===== testing package: py_tools-0.0.1-py27_0 =====
import: u'twitter_functions'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/curtis/miniconda2/conda-bld/test-tmp_dir/run_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    import twitter_functions
ImportError: No module named twitter_functions
TESTS FAILED: py_tools-0.0.1-py27_0
```

Here is a link to my Github that contains the directory with my Conda package that I'm trying to build.

https://github.com/CurtLH/py_tools/tree/develop

Do you know what I'm doing wrong when in either my meta.yaml file or somewhere else?

Comment: You didn't add the link

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just edited it to include the link to my GitHub

Answer (score 2):

The correct import test would be `src.twitter_tools`, since you've named your package directory `src`. You can also see the Python packaging documentation to help in naming your package, etc.: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html I'd recommend you start by making sure that everything works when you run `python setup.py develop` before you make a conda package.